# How to convert this Struts2 to displaytag (date comparison)

Tags: java, struts2, displaytag

I had Struts2 code to show a button based on the result of a date comparison like this (note that this is a simplified example of what I actually have):

```
<s:iterator value="myList">
    <s:if test="%{getDate().compareTo(getNow()) > 0}">
        // Show the item
    </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

I have since converted the display of the result set to use displaytag.  How would I do the above using display tag.  This is what I've tried.

```
<display:table name="myList" pagesize="50" id="row">
    <display:column title="Item">
        <s:if test="%{#attr.row.endDt.compareTo(#attr.row.now()) > 0}"><%--does NOT work--%>
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```

What is the correct syntax of the `<s:if>` statement?
Or can this not be done using displaytag + Struts2?

Comment: Given that you use `getDate().compareTo(getNow()) > 0` in the first, working expression, have you tried `#attr.row.getDate().compareTo(#attr.row.getNow()) > 0`? It seems more logical to me.

Comment: @JBNizet I didn't even think of that! But, unfortunately, didn't quite work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are likely multiple solutions but, this ended up working for me:

```
<display:table name="myList" pagesize="50" id="row">
    <display:column title="Item">
        <s:set name="endDt" value="#attr.row.endDt"/>
        <s:set name="now" value="now" />
        <s:if test="%{#endDt.compareTo(#now) > 0}">
           <span>w00 h00!</span>
        </s:if>
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `#attr.row` as index to reference the element in the list should work:

```
<display:table name="myList" pagesize="50" id="row">
    <display:column title="Item">
        <s:if test="myList[%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}].endDt.compareTo(myList[%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}].now()) > 0}">
           <span>Let's rock</span>
        </s:if>
    </display:column>
</display:table>
```

Note: is `getNow()` a function coming from the iterated object ?

This seems strange to me, shouldn't it be a common function, from the baseAction from example ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but didn't quite work for me. `getnow` isn't actually a property of the bean but is coming from the Action class, from baseAction as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be use a displaytag decorator.

```
 public String getLink()
 {
    YourObject yourObject = (YourObject) getCurrentRowObject();
    //Do your checks....
    return "<a href="#">your link</a>";

 }
```